# durandal widget data bind and update by ajax

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, widget, durandal

I want to use a durandual widget in a view and the widget bind-data should be able to update by the AJAX call from page's view model js. I post my code in following

**Here is my page Model: which shoud update email to "Hello after ajax call"**

```
email= ko.observable('Login/Register2222');
        var self = this;
        if ($('#btn-login').html() == 'Login') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "api/User/Login",
                data: $('#form-user-login').serialize()
            })
            .success(function (response) {
                if (response == true) {
                    $('#loginModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#LoginBtn').html('My Profile');
                    $("#LoginBtn").attr("data-target", "#profileModal");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "Post",
                        url: "api/User/getLoginUserInfo",
                        data: $('#form-user-login').serialize()
                    })
                    .success(function (response) {
                        self.email("Hello");
                        router.navigate('#Test');
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

**Here is my page HTML with widget call**

```
<div data-bind="widget: { kind: 'email', email: email, prompt: 'Email', id: 'Profile_Email', name: 'UserCode' }"></div>
```

**Here is my Widget View Model js**

```
define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app', 'knockout'], function (router, app, ko, composition) {

function emailWidget() {
    var self = this;
    self.activate = function (options) {
        self.email = ko.observable(ko.unwrap(options.email));
        self.prompt = ko.observable(ko.unwrap(options.prompt));
        self.id = ko.unwrap(options.id);
        self.name = ko.unwrap(options.name);
    };
}

return emailWidget;});
```

**Here is my widget view html**

```
<input type="email"  placeholder="Email" class="form-control" style="text-align:right" data-bind="value: email, attr: { 'id': id, 'name':name}"/>
```

The email value will update if I am not using it with a widget 
With a widget the value will stay at 'Login/Register2222' 
Please Help

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? The reason I ask is because the `$ajax().success()` function, as you have implemented it, is deprecated as of jQuery v1.8.

Comment: I am using 2.0.3. the success event still working fine with other functions

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem, and i know the reason why this comes but i dont think that there would be a solution to it.

the place where we do this:

all the accepting variables that are: email, prompt, id and name are not observables. They are coming as properties (in ur case, properties of Options) function (options). and then you assign them to observables.

therefore we have an observable in our caller viewmodel , we have another observable in our widget but the link between the two is a non-observable.